# Computation of Single-particle Density of States for a particle in a container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

I have a system of N particles stored in a cylindrical container (radius $R$, height $L$). I need to determine the single-particle density of states, which we've defined as:
$$ g(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{h^3}\int d\mathbf{q}d\mathbf{p} \delta\left(\mathcal{H}(\mathbf{p,q})-\epsilon \right) $$
knowing that the Hamiltonian of each particle has the following form:
$$ H = \frac{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}{2m} -\frac{u_0 z}{L} $$
and that the conjugated momenta are unbounded, namely the extrema of integration for each of the $p_i$'s are infinite:
$$p_i \in (-\infty, +\infty) \equiv \mathbb{R}, i = \{x,y,z\} $$
The reason why I am coming here is because I'm having trouble finishing the exercise.

> First of all, I noticed that the integration in $x,y$ is trivial, therefore I used standard polar coordinates and got:
>  $$ g(\epsilon) = 2\pi \frac{R^2}{2}\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{0}^{L} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} d\mathbf{p} \delta\left(\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}- \frac{u_0 z}{L}-\epsilon\right) \right) dz $$

> Then I introduced spherical coordinates for the integration in space of momenta, namely $\theta, \phi, p = p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2$, where the integration along the angular coordinates is, again, trivial:
>  $$ g(\epsilon) = \pi R^2\frac{1}{h^3}4\pi \int_{0}^{L} \left(  \int_{0}^{\infty}dp \text{ } p^2\delta\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}- \frac{u_o z}{L}-\epsilon \right)   \right)$$
>  Then, I performed two ulterior changes of variable:
>  $$ \frac{p^2}{2m} \rightarrow t, \frac{u_0 z}{L} \rightarrow s$$
>  hereby obtaining:
>  $$g(\epsilon) = \frac{4\sqrt{2}\pi^2 R^2Lm^{3/2}}{u_0h^3} \int_{0}^{u_0}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty} dt\text{ }\sqrt{2mt}\delta( t - (s+\epsilon ) \right) ds $$
>  which yields:
>  $$ g(\epsilon) = \frac{4\sqrt{2}\pi^2 R^2Lm^{3/2}}{u_0h^3} \int_{0}^{u_0}\sqrt{\epsilon + s} \text{ } \theta(\epsilon+s) ds $$
>  Performing a final change of variable:
>  $$ \epsilon + s \rightarrow \xi, \text{  } \alpha = \frac{4\sqrt{2}\pi^2 R^2Lm^{3/2}}{u_0h^3} $$

After quite some easy computations, I've come to this final expression:
$$g(\epsilon) = \alpha \int_{\epsilon}^{u_0 + \epsilon} \sqrt{\xi} \text{ }\theta(\xi)d\xi $$
The problem is that I actually don't know how to compute the integral since I'm not sure I know how to treat the theta function in accordance with the extrema of integration, I even asked my professor who, after taking a rapid look, told me, in a very cryptic manner, to go through all the possible cases and treat them separately and then reconstruct the result, which I honestly don't know how to interpret. If somebody could help me compute this final integral, I'd be very grateful, as always.

Comment: Please see: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/

Comment: I read that long ago. But I'm not asking people to check if my previous computations are correct, which I'm pretty sure they are (I just added that for context ). I'm genuinely asking how to compute the final integral, which I think is not against the policy of this site. I'll make the previous computations hidden so that the question is more suitable

Comment: Oh... So, if that is all you are asking, maybe don't have such a giant preamble to the real question. It would also be helpful if you actually state your question as a question... All you wrote was "I actually don't know how to go on." From this is it not clear that you want help with the last integral.

Comment: Yes I reckon, I will edit the question as soon as possible and follow your suggestions indeed. Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: Can we assume that $u_0$ is positive?

Comment: @hft My professor did not specify the sign but I assume with almost 100% certainty it is indeed a positive quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I finally get to:
> $$g(\epsilon) = \alpha \int_{\epsilon}^{u_0 + \epsilon} \sqrt{\xi} \text{ }\theta(\xi)d\xi $$
> The problem is that I actually don't know how to go on...

Per the comments, OP wants help with the last integration (quoted above).

I will assume that $u_0$ is positive.

---

Suppose that $\epsilon\le-u_0$, in that case the $\theta$ function can never have a non-zero argument and the density of states is zero:
$$
g(\epsilon) = 0 \qquad\epsilon \le -u_0
$$

---

Suppose that $\epsilon = -u_0 + q$, where $q$ is positive, but $q\le u_0$ (this means the energy is still not positive, but $u_0+\epsilon$ can be positive):
$$
g(\epsilon) = \alpha \int_{-u_0 + q}^{q} d\xi \theta(\xi)\sqrt{\xi}
= \alpha \int_0^q d\xi \sqrt{\xi}
$$

---

Suppose that the energy is greater than zero, then the $\theta$ function is always satisfied:
$$
g(\epsilon) = \alpha \int_{\epsilon}^{\epsilon+u_0}\sqrt{\xi}d\xi
$$

Comment: may I ask you whether I managed to hide the computations or not? I'm not quite sure I did it correctly

Comment: You mean in your edited post? I don't think they are hidden, they appear to me as indented/gray comments and an added "!" character.

Comment: Now I see it as hidden ("spoiler")

Comment: yep I managed to somehow do it